# how to pass data to multiple viewcontrollers from the same button

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

Here's another version of one of the most popular questions on stackoverflow. Sorry. Thank you.

I have a viewcontroller that has 30 buttons. Each of these buttons can segue to one of 20 viewcontrollers based on a variable that is sent from a previous viewcontroller.

I know how to send data from one viewcontroller to another, and I know how to have a button connect to multiple viewcontrollers dependent on a passed variable, but I don't know how to pass a variable from a button to whatever viewcontroller is specified from the variable...

My viewcontroller looks like this:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if passedvariable == "A" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToA", sender: self)
    if passedvariable == "B" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToB", sender: self)
    }
```

I tried adding something like this...

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if passedvariable == "A" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToA", sender: self)       
            let send = segue.destination as! AViewController
            send.NewVariableToSend = (sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)!}
    }
```

But that's not working...  I feel like I'm close but can't connect the dots yet. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing the actual segue from the IBAction method of your `UIButton`?
This approach is wrong. Use `PrepareForSegue` method to pass your data to next ViewController. Its a predefined method so all you need is to override this method in your `ViewController` class.

Try this..
**Note:**
`guard let` is used to get rid of crash if you tried to pass any nil value to your next `ViewController`.

```
@IBAction func didTapButton (_ sender: Any) {
        //First get the clickedButton Object if you do not have IBOutlet of that button
        guard let clickedButton = sender as? UIButton else {return}
        //Pass the clicked button to Segue perform as a sender
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: clickedButton)

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
            //Now get you destination viewcontroller and type cast it into your desired ViewController class
            guard let nextVC = segue.destination as? YourViewController else {return}
            //Now convert the sender into your clicked button because you have previously set the clickedButton as sender when you try to perform this segue
            guard let clickedButton = sender as? UIButton else {return}
            //Now Simply assign this to nextVC
            nextVC.button = clickedButton
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Still definitely figuring it out... How do I get the clickedButton Object ?

Comment: In you IBAction of button click there is a parameter with name sender. This will bring the clicked button automatically.